# LINQ - To Get Year from Date which is of Type String

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have this LINQ query:

```
  hdms = from t in db.HOLIDAY
         join t1 in db.EMPLOYEE on t.UPDATED_BY equals t1.EMP_CODE                               
         where
             t.HOLIDAY_NAME == searchtext &&                                   
             t.DOH.Value.Year == 2016
         orderby
             t.DOH
         select new HOLIDAYDETAILS
         {
             HOLIDAY_NAME = t.HOLIDAY_NAME,
             DOH = t.DOH,
             EMP_NAME = t1.EMP_NAME                                   
         };
```

While executing this, below error occurs:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error comes under `Value` in `t.DOH.Value.Year = 2016`.

Here type of `t.DOH` is `string` and value is `2016-04-14`

I have also tried this one:

```
       hdms = from t in db.HOLIDAY                           
                       where                               
                           DateTime.ParseExact(t.DOH, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Year == DateTime.Now.Year
                       orderby
                           t.DOH
                       select new HOLIDAYDETAILS
                       {                               
                           DOH = t.DOH                               
                       };
```

Now got this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is there any other way to convert string to date type in LINQ?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question - `DOH` is a `string` and `string` does not have a property or field called `Value`. You will need to check that the string _starts with_ 2016.

Comment: Or better, change your model so that `DOH` is a `DateTime?` which you appear to expect it to be.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not fond of dates stored as strings myself. By not fond, I mean "hate with a fiery passion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DOH` is of type string you could use `StartsWith` to check if the string starts with 2016.

```
where
  t.HOLIDAY_NAME == searchtext &&                                   
  t.DOH.StartsWith("2016")
```

A better option would be to change your datatype of DOH to `DateTime`/`DatetTime?`, to get better support when working with date and time values. Then you can leave your query as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse DateTime from string like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(t.DOH, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Then you can get year value using [DateTimeVariable].Year